# Porque em PHP string pode virar função?

Tags: php

No exemplo tenho uma função com nome de `funcao`, que tem como objetivo apenas exibir o valor do parâmetro na tela.

Ao criar uma `string` com o nome da função e chama-la como uma função, ela será executada:

```
<?php

function funcao($parametro = "default") {
    echo $parametro . "<br/>\n" ;
}

$func = "funcao"; 
$func("kirotawa");

$func = "FUNCAO";
$func();

?>
```

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/s3wwOj)

Porque acontece de poder chamar a função da seguinte maneira?

Comment: Por que que pode ?

Comment: Essa é a pergunta kk, acho que é por causa da tipagem automática do `php` e ao chamar com `()` ele interpreta que aquela `string` é o nome de uma função daí tenta chama-la. Mas queria um explicação melhor.

Comment: Tem duplicata disto. O duro é achar

Comment: @bigown é mesma coisa que as variables variables?

Comment: @rray não sei, não vi essa? :P

Comment: Realmente, provavelmente tem duplicata  mas procurei e não achei nada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php), fala que se o valor da variável for o mesmo de alguma função, seguindo de parenteses a função de tal nome é invocada. Isso é chamado no php de variable functions

```
function wow(){
    echo 'wow';
}


$function = 'wow';
$function();
```

Answer (score 5):

o mesmo funciona com variaveis variaveis, o nome é meio estranho, mas existe como no exemplo abaixo:

```
$vara = "c";
$varb = "vara";
echo $$varb;
```

> c

Isso acontece pois pode-se usar o valor de uma variável para chamar funções, ou acessar outras variáveis, garantindo assim uma maior flexibilidade da linguagem

**Como o PHP interpreta a ultima linha?**

```
echo $$varb;
```

substitui a primeira variavel pelo seu valor ($varb por vara);

```
echo $vara;
```

substitui a segunda variavel pelo seu valor ($vara por c);

```
echo c;
```

e imprime o valor na tela

Comment: Essa foi mito, demorei 20 minutos pra entender. Por mim pode fechar a pergunta.

Comment: Tava brincando dos 20 minutos, não precisava explicar passo a passo. Rs

Comment: foi só para não deixar nenhuma duvida caso alguém não entenda :)